# spyder-error:('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (77) Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4 required. (77) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, odbc

I have updated my python/Anoconda version. What this code supposed to do is connect Teradata using python to automate process... But now, it doesn't allow me even connect with odbc driver with below error message. Could anyone please let me know what should I do to solve it? Thank you!

('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (77)  Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4 required. (77) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Below is my code.

```
import pyodbc as od
od.pooling = False
usr = input('Teradata username?:')
pwd = input('Teradata password?:')
con = od.connect(dsn = 'TEREDWPD', driver = 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20', user = usr, password = pwd)
sql = con.cursor()
ref = ['Comment', 'Field']
for i in range(0, len(ref)):
    print('running', ref[i])
    txt = open('\\\\route' + ref[i] + '_Report'+'.sql', 'r')
    qry = txt.read()
    txt.close() 
sql.commit()
sql.execute(qry)
sql.commit()
input('operation successful: press any key -> ')
con.close()
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do... download and install `Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4`. You can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30679)